# print array contents to a file using gdb

Tags: c++, c, arrays, debugging, gdb

I am debugging a `while` loop using conditional breakpoints in [gdb](/questions/tagged/gdb). There are multiple large arrays that are getting created in `while` loop. I would like to print them in a file while debugging so that I can compare using `diff` later.

I am able to visualize content at the console using the following command :

```
(gdb) p *&ff[0]@10
```

where `ff` is my array. Kindly tell how I can redirect them to text file.

Comment: Why are you using `*&` while printing?

Comment: * is for the value to be printed

Comment: You can use `(gdb) p ff[0]@10`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use:

```
(gdb) set logging file large_array.txt
(gdb) set logging on
```

By default the logging file name is `gdb.txt`

You can find more details at: https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Logging-Output.html

There is also one WA `gdb --args a.out arg1 ... |& tee gdb_out.txt`

Comment: This works, But the format is a problem. I would like to if there is something like redirection of array contents to a file..

Comment: @ShreyaKhare If you can change the source code, you can print the arrays in required format.

Answer (score 2):

You set logging by using

```
(gdb) set logging on
```

after this, all command output will be output in a file called "gdb.txt". You can find the array content in the file.